# Windows char and Char types and strings with Console::WriteLine()

Tags: c++, .net

I am writing a Winsock application and at one point I need to form the tcp message which is an http get request for a webpage.

```
char clientmessage[] = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n";
Console::WriteLine(clientmessage);
```

When I try to print out the message useing     `Console::WriteLine()` method it prints `True`. I've considered it may be an issue with the method and maybe I nee to use `puts()` as is done in this tutorial.
http://www.binarytides.com/winsock-socket-programming-tutorial/

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So this call writes true or some other?

Comment: If you want to use managed C++ (i..e [C++/CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI) and especially the .NET functions and classes you need to use the .NET types as well.

Comment: yes in the console at runtime it prints "True" instead of the exact string that i would like.

Comment: The reason I am using the `char[]` type instead of `String^` is because the  WinSock api `int send(SOCKET, const char*, int, int)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like it implicitly converts an unmanaged pointer to `System.Boolean`.
In order to use .NET APIs, you need to marshal the parameters. In this case you need to marshal `clientmessage` into `System::String^`. You can do this with the `System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::PtrToStringAnsi()` method.

```
char clientmessage[] = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n";
System::String^ str = System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::PtrToStringAnsi(static_cast<System::IntPtr>(clientmessage));
Console::WriteLine(str);
```

Comment: Or better yet: `msclr::interop::marshal_as<System::String^>(clientmessage)` (with `#include <msclr/marshal.h>`), which is the [unified way to convert strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384865.aspx) in C++/CLI